# How to get all intermediary values of `reduce` in addition to the final result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reduce, python-itertools, functools

A call to [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) returns only the final result:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> f = lambda x, y: x + y
>>> reduce(f, a)
15
```

Instead of writing a loop myself, does a function exist which returns the intermediary values, too?

```
[3, 6, 10, 15]
```

(This is only a simple example, I'm not trying to calculate the cumulative sum - the solution should work for arbitrary `a` and `f`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], lambda x, y: x+y))[1:]
[3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Note that the order of parameters is switched relative to `functools.reduce()`.

Also, the default `func` (the second parameter) is a sum (like `operator.add`), so in your case, it's technically optional:

```
>>> list(accumulate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))[1:]  # default func: sum
[3, 6, 10, 15]
```

And finally, it's worth noting that `accumulate()` will include the first term in the sequence, hence why the result is indexed from `[1:]` above.

---

In your edit, you noted that...

> This is only a simple example, I'm not trying to calculate the cumulative sum - the solution should work for arbitrary a and f.

The nice thing about `accumulate()` is that it is flexible about the callable it will take.  It only demands a callable that is a function of two parameters.

For instance, builtin [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max) satisfies that:

```
>>> list(accumulate([1, 10, 4, 2, 17], max))
[1, 10, 10, 10, 17]
```

This is a longer form of using the unnecessary lambda:

```
>>> # Don't do this
>>> list(accumulate([1, 10, 4, 2, 17], lambda x, y: max(x, y)))
[1, 10, 10, 10, 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y=np.cumsum(x) # gets you the cumulative sum
y=list(y[1:]) #  remove the first number
print(y)
#[3, 6, 10, 15]
```